# 'if' statement is not working. I am trying to use a class button to 'clear all' or 'select all' radio buttons. Why?

Tags: jquery, radio-button

The thing I can't work out is the 'if' statement doesn't seem to work the right way round it works backwards?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".clearAllBtn").click(function() {
    var txt = $(this).html();
    if ($(this).html() === 'Clear all') {
      $(".radioFit").each(function() {
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
      });
      $(this).html("Select all")
    } else {
      $(".radioFit").each(function() {
        $(this).prop('checked', true);
      });
      $(this).html("Clear all")
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant HTML to make a [mcve]

Comment: *debug* your code - what is the *exact* value of `$(this).html()` on the first call?  It's likely there are spaces there if you've laid-out your HTML.

Comment: Without seeing the HTML, it sounds like you have a misunderstanding of how `radio` buttons work.  Only one *radio* in a group can be selected at a time.  Here's an example with two radio "groups" - selecting "all" only selects 2, as expected:   https://jsfiddle.net/j3c9efh1/  as noted above, please include the *relevant HTML* so we can determine if you have radio groups, separate radios (why would you?) or *checkboxes*.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very NON-DRY and hard to read.

You likely wanted this if it had been CHECKBOXES

Note, I added a data attribute so you can have sets of checkboxes.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".toggleButton").click(function() {
    let txt = $(this).text();
    let check = txt === 'Select all';
    $(`.${this.dataset.class}`).prop('checked', check);
    $(this).text(check ? "Clear all" : "Select all")
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <button type="button" class="toggleButton" data-class="checkFit1">Select all</button>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkFit1"/> Check 1</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkFit1"/> Check 2</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkFit1"/> Check 3</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkFit1"/> Check 4</label>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <button type="button" class="toggleButton" data-class="checkFit2">Select all</button>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkFit2"/> Check 1</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkFit2"/> Check 2</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkFit2"/> Check 3</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkFit2"/> Check 4</label>
</div>
```

If you only have one set, then do this

```js
$(function() {
  $('.toggleButton').click(function() {
    let txt = $(this).text();
    let check = txt === 'Select all';
    $('.checkFit').prop('checked', check);
    $(this).text(check ? "Clear all" : "Select all")
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <button type="button" class="toggleButton">Select all</button>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkFit"/> Check 1</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkFit"/> Check 2</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkFit"/> Check 3</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkFit"/> Check 4</label>
```

Comment: Thank you, appreciate the solution - using checkboxes is the correct way!!